# Ruby Time#to_date() method returns wrong date

Tags: ruby

We're using Ruby 1.9.3, and I found what appears to be a strange Ruby error with [Time#to_date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date)

`Time.new(1).to_date` returns 3 January 0001 when it should return 1 January 0001.

I discovered this problem accidentally.  It seems if I call `.to_datetime.to_date`,
the result would be correct.

I also found some other related weirdness.  See the irb console output below.
(Note I'm using irb, not rails console to ensure that it's only Ruby I'm using,
not any add-on stuff of Rails.)

```
>> require "Time"
=> true
>> Time.new(1).to_date
=> #<Date: 0001-01-03 ((1721426j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(1).to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 0001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00 ((1721423j,82800s,0n),+3600s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(1).to_datetime.to_date
=> #<Date: 0001-01-01 ((1721424j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(100).to_date
=> #<Date: 0100-01-03 ((1757585j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(1969).to_date
=> #<Date: 1969-01-01 ((2440223j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(500).to_date
=> #<Date: 0499-12-31 ((1903682j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(1000).to_date
=> #<Date: 0999-12-27 ((2086303j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(2014).to_date
=> #<Date: 2014-01-01 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Time.new(1,1,1,10,0,0, "+00:00").to_date
=> #<Date: 0001-01-03 ((1721426j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> DateTime.new(1,1,1,10,0,0, "+00:00").to_date
=> #<Date: 0001-01-01 ((1721424j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Could someone explain why this happens?  Is this related to Unix time somehow?

It seems DateTime is more reliable, at least with Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Conversions/to_date says this method is deprecated

Comment: This `to_date` method you mentioned seems to be of String class, not Time or DateTime class.

Comment: @emaillenin [`Time#to_date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date) is implemented by the Ruby's stdlib.

Comment: I've got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_date' for 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0220:Time` in irb, ruby 2.1.1 but it works in rails console

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko `require 'Time'`

Comment: @emaillenin it's not required.
     :004 > Time.new(1)
     => 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0220

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko but to call `to_date` you need to require Time

Comment: The time library is named 'time' (lowercase), not 'Time' (capitalized).  Are you running in an OS where filenames are case insensitive, such as Windows?

Comment: The class named Time is defined in file time.rb.  You use lower-case with Ruby require.  http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/require.htm

Comment: I just tried the first line in JRuby jirb and got #<Date: 0001-01-01 ((1721426j,0s,0n),+0s,-Infj)> but this is now a 2014-06-10 posting. I'm using JRuby 1.7.11 There is one fault in DateTime that annoys me. DateTime.jd(0) should show a time of 12 hours not #<DateTime: -4712-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> T00 as you may see. I don't think 'Matz' wrote this part. Just remember to add 0.5 like so DateTime.jd(0 + 0.5) and it corrects any call to this method. #<DateTime: -4712-01-01T12:00:00+00:00 ((0j,43200s,0.0n),+0s,2299161j)> I like history too. see Joseph Justus Scaliger

Comment: Now I tried Time.new(1).to_datetime and got just the opposite and same as yours Zack. #<DateTime: 0001-01-03T00:00:00+00:00 ((1721426j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> I also want to mention that I did not need require 'time' only require 'date'

Comment: Time.new(1).to_datetime.to_date leaves it that way too. Now do you see a reason to start with Date or DateTime instead of just Time? Date.new(1) # => #<Date: 0001-01-01 ((1721424j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> DateTime.new(1) # => #<DateTime: 0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((1721424j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> So you got your reason why but you never asked for a solution. Sorry!

Comment: Addendum non Latin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#History

Comment: There is a method in Date class Date#to_time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of how leap year is implemented in the ruby `Time.to_date` method.

Note that the cutoff for your strange behavior happens between 1583 and 1582:

```
>    Time.new(1583).to_date
=> #<Date: 1583-01-01 ((2299239j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>    Time.new(1582).to_date
=> #<Date: 1581-12-22 ((2298874j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Where 1583's date is correct but 1582's is incorrect. If you look at the [source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/ext/date/date_core.c#8439) for `Time.to_date`, you can see that it always considers a date to be a [Gregorian calendar date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) - i.e. it includes leap year. Also note that the switch to the Gregorian calendar was in 1582, explaining the cutoff for the behavior above. (For those really interested in the source code, note that the call to [decode_year](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/ext/date/date_core.c#1305) is passing -1 as the `style` parameter, which always makes all calls to that function use a Gregorian calendar date.)

So that means any dates before 1583 will be incorrect when displaying them with this method.

Comment: Thanks for the salient explanation. There's a bit of European history that's fascinating.  I also tested out your theory by running this on console: (1..2014).each {|x| a=Time.new(x).to_date.to_s; b=DateTime.new(x,1,1).to_date.to_s; puts b + " " + a if a != b}

Comment: I try to include European history in my posts whenever possible :)